# remove the value in a list based on the condition

Tags: c#, .net, list

I need to remove a particular value from the list based on the condition

```
skillResult.Where(search => 
    resrictedskills.Any(resrictedskill => 
        search.L5_Id.ToString() == resrictedskill.CRTS_SKILLID.ToString()
        && resrictedskill.CRTS_SKILLTYPE.ToLower() == "primary"
    )
).ToList()
 .ForEach(skill => skill.isRestrictedpri = true);
```

I tried using remove but I am getting error "cannot convert from void to particular list model"

```
skillResult.Remove(
    skillResult.Where(search =>
        resrictedskills.Any(resrictedskill =>
            search.L5_Id.ToString() == resrictedskill.CRTS_SKILLID.ToString()
            && resrictedskill.CRTS_SKILLTYPE.ToLower() == "primary"
        )
    ).ToList()
     .ForEach(skill => skill.isRestrictedpri = true)
);
```

Comment: `ForEach` is defined as `void List<T>.ForEach(Action<T>)` ... so what you expected ?

Comment: why are you having `ForEach(skill => skill.isRestrictedpri = true)` ?

Comment: You're trying to do everything in one line of code.  Don't.  It's not only possible to have more than one line of code in your program, it's somewhat encouraged when you're performing more than one operation.

Comment: I need to set skill.isRestrictedpri  flag if the condition inside the where condition is satisfied
but If I remove this also I am facing the same issue

Comment: @kang_mi_rae: The `Remove()` method expects *one* object to remove from the list.  Which object are you trying to remove?  First identify that object.  Then remove it from the list.  Then perform your `ForEach` operation on the remaining list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Remove()` expects one item and returns a `bool` telling whether the item was found and could be removed.

You must use `RemoveAll` which expects a condition and returns and `int` telling how many items have been removed.

Since none of the two methods return skill objects, you cannot chain the `ForEach` on them to set a property of the skills. Therefore, you need two statements.

```cs
skillResult.RemoveAll(skillResult => resrictedskills
    .Any(restrictedSkill =>
        skillResult.L5_Id == restrictedSkill.CRTS_SKILLID &&
        restrictedSkill.CRTS_SKILLTYPE.ToLower() == "primary"
    )
);
skillResult.ForEach(skill => skill.isRestrictedpri = true);
```